# DropdownList Linked to a Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, drop-down-menu

I am trying to display the selectedIndex of my dropdownlist in the textBox (field number 2) and in my ajax htmlEditor (field number 3). I already can show field number 1 on my dropdown, but I cant seem to show anything on the other boxes, all I get are errors :(, implying that the dataSource has not any items which is weird. Here are my classes.

Messages.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Messages.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASF.HC.JobApplication.Admin.Messages" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Messages</h2>    
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <legend>Pick the template to use:</legend>
    <asp:dropdownlist id ="ddlTemplate" runat ="server" Height="38px" Width="397px">
                  <asp:listitem value ="1"> Juan Valdez </asp:listitem >
                  <asp:listitem Value ="2"> Querido bebe</asp:listitem>
                  </asp:dropdownlist >     
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textDos" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" MaxLength="40"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="textoTemplate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDetails" 
                EnableSanitization="false" DisplaySourceTab="true" >               
            </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

Message.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Messages : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadList();
        }

        public void loadList()
        {
            try
            {
                BO.Messages template = new BO.Messages();
                ddlTemplate.DataSource = template.GetAll();
                ddlTemplate.DataValueField = "Title";
                DataSet ds = new DataSet("Templates");
                ddlTemplate.DataSource = ds;
                ddlTemplate.DataBind();
                ddlTemplate.SelectedIndexChanged += DdlTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged;
                textDos.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        private void DdlTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //when we change the dropdownlist we need to get the student id and set it to the textbox
            DropDownList mydropdownlist = sender as DropDownList;
            textDos.Text = mydropdownlist.SelectedValue;

        }


    }
```

Been checking this error all day long, with no plausible answer and can not detect what am I doing wrong.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Okay, first of all, I wish you could give more details about your code. In your loadList method, you are setting the DataSource of your DropDownList two times. First, you set it to GetAll method of your BO.Messages class, then you create a Empty DataSet and and overwrite the DataSource. I did not understand it at all. Can you explain me what are you trying to do here? Also, could you share the code of your BO.Messages class?

Comment: Also, you are calling your fields by numbers, I suppose field 1 must be your DropDownList, field 2 must be your textBox named "txtDos", and your third field is missing. There is no "txtDetails" implementation, only the HtmlEditorExtender wich have his TargetControlID pointing to it. This will cause a NullReferenceException.